# Inheritance In code first ASP.NET MVC 4 EF5 -> Get type

Tags: inheritance, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, view, entity-framework-5

this may be quite simple but cant figure it out. Say I have an "Item" model and the models which inherit from that are "DVD", "CD", "GAME" for example, I would like to be able to go into the index view for Item and get the type of item it is. Obviously GetType() isnt going to work. Anyway I can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't GetType() work?

I assume the model you are passing from the controller to the view is a DVD, CD or Game but the model declared in the view is an Item?

In this mini program (LinqPad - Yay) the output is "this is a CD". Is that not what you want?

```
void Main()
{
    Item cd = new CD();
    Type modelType = cd.GetType();
    if(modelType == typeof(CD)){Console.WriteLine("this is a CD");}
}

public class Item{}

public class CD: Item{}
```

Caveat: I haven't tested this in a View as VS2012 update 2 has just killed VS (Not Responding). Ho hum.

Comment: No it gives the full path but for item. I just need something in the view that I van use which detects the "descriminator" or type. If I write a method else where for that, where would it be and how would it be written? Just want the model name for that item in the database

Answer (score 0):

> Your `Type` is your discriminator.

See this post of mine earlier - [Entity Framework 5 - Enum based Discriminator for derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859452/entity-framework-5-enum-based-discriminator-for-derived-classes/15864906#15864906)

You can use `is` operator to test for the Type.

Or make your property - if you really wish to do so (but I never had a need for that)...

```
public class Item
{
    [NotMapped()]
    public virtual MyEnum MyEnum { get { return MyEnum.Item; } }
}

public class DVD: Item
{
    [NotMapped()]
    public override MyEnum MyEnum { get { return MyEnum.DVD; } }
}

public class CD: Item
{
    [NotMapped()]
    public override MyEnum MyEnum { get { return MyEnum.CD; } }
}
```

But I'd always just do the `if(item is DVD)`

Or do `.GetType().Name` if that's what you want really.

Comment: Thank you for the link but how do I do the last if (entity is MyBaseClass) or .OfType<MyBaseClass>(); options, where do I put them if I want to get my type in the Index view. Thank you

Comment: your view is tied to your model - i.e. e.g. DVD - you have all you need. I posted some more code - depends on what you want to do. Edit your question to add the MVC view code - and where is that you're stuck

Comment: You may need to brush up on the MVC coding techniques, I believe that's what's bothering you. Take a look at how to do the usual coding in the view and based on the model that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Right everyone, easy apparently
In the view where ever you want, just write:

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.GetType().Name)
```